# Ignore all checkstyle warnings for deprecated classes and methods

Tags: java, checkstyle

Can I somehow ignore any warning for deprecated class?

**For example:**
I had following warnings `AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters`, `NonEmptyAtclauseDescription` for deprecated class.

How to **ignore** all of them?

Comment: I do not want to remove depreceted warning.
I want to remove all warnings that are inside deprecated class.

Answer (score 2):

Checkstyle allows you to write [your own custom filters](https://checkstyle.org/writingfilters.html). You can use [`SuppressWarningsFilter`](https://checkstyle.org/apidocs/index.html?com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/class-use/Filter.html) as a basis, because this filter is filtering based on annotations as well. You'd just need to change the annotation that you're looking for.

```
public class SuppressWarningsFilter
    extends AutomaticBean
    implements Filter {

    @Override
    protected void finishLocalSetup() {
        // No code by default
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(AuditEvent event) {
        return !SuppressWarningsHolder.isSuppressed(event);
    }
}
```

Pretty simple, but all of the logic is in `SuppressWarningsHolder`. That code is a few hundred lines, but you should be able to copy and paste a lot of it, and probably remove a large chuck as well.

---

I've implemented this: https://github.com/michaelboyles/checkstyle-annotation-filter. I'll make it available via the central repository at some point.

Comment: I might implement this and publish it on GitHub later tonight, if you're lucky!

Comment: @StanislavMukhametshin I've updated the answer with the implementation

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add the line below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

It will ignore all deprecated methods in your code. 
I hope this will help.